# MVC user input for int x datestart and dateend variables for stored procedured parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, entity-framework-6

So i have an mvc 5  using entity framework 6  and i use the chinook database.I have made the mvc everything works ok and i now have to make some sql commands like show the X records from datestart to dateend from a table. I have made the sql command and i  wanted to use it as a stored procedure on my mvc but i can't find how to show to the user

CHOOSE INT X

CHOOSE DATESTART

CHOOSE DATEEND

and pass his inputs from the view to the controller to my stored procedure parameters.
Do i need to do this with some short of mapping?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have view model properties like ResultSize, DateStart and DateEnd, just map those properties to the stored procedure parameters:

```
public ActionResult YourAction(YourViewModel vm)
{
   using (var ctxt = new YourDBContext())
   {
      var yourResultSet = ctxt.Database.SqlQuery<YourViewModel>("EXEC YourSP @param1, @param2, @param3", vm.ResultSize, vm.DateStart, vm.DateEnd).Select(s => new YourViewModel
      {
        //YourViewModel properties from database code here
        DateStart = s.DateStart,
        //rest of code                  
      }).ToList();
   }
}
```

Hope I have answered your question.